# How do I keep track of all inputs that have been submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to keep track every time someone submits a name using `data-name` only. How do I alert the user to let them know that the contents were posted to the website or not and what other names have been submitted.

```
<div id="container">
  <form method="POST" action="#">
    <label class="large">Please enter your name
       <input id="textbox" class="name" data-name="" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{1-45}">
    </label>
  </form>
</div>
```

This is the JQuery I'm using:

```
 //When the form is submitted
$("#form").submit(function(){
  //get the value of the input
  var input = $('#textbox').val();

  //insert it into the data-name attribute
  var name = $("#textbox").attr("data-name", input);

  //Aler the user 
  $("input[data-name]").val(function(){
    alert($(this).data('name'));
  });

});
```

Comment: How are the data getting persisted? Submitting a form generally involves a page refresh or redirect, so you'd want to update the value via some kind of server-side code. Also, I'm not sure why you're using a function in `val()`. You should just use `$("input[data-name]").val(name)`, but it's a bit confusing since you've just pulled the value from `$('#textbox').val()` so the whole code is a no-op.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your jquery selector is incorrect.

`$("#form")` means that it is targeting an element with the id of "form". In order to make that work, you would need to give your form element an id of form. E.g.
`<form id="form" method="POST" action="#">`

In order to alert the value of the textbox however, you do not need to put the value into a data-name attribute but instead get the value out of the form when submitting.

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e){
    alert(e.target.foo.value);
})
```

See the following fiddle, for an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/dgw3bw63/

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to output all of the previous inputs that had been submitted?